# on duplicate key update with a condition?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have something like:

```
INSERT INTO tbl (count,otherID) VALUES (2,'a') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE count = 2
```

I would like to update count only if the new value is greater than the current value. So let's say there is already a record with count: 4 and otherID: 'a' that `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE count = 3` should not be triggered

How can i achive this?

can i use if? `... UPDATE count = IF (NEWVALUE > count) NEWVALUE else count`

Comment: Are these two differnet values: `2` and `3`? Or it's a typo and they are the same?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Another option:

```
INSERT INTO tbl (count, otherID) 
  VALUES (2, 'a') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
  count = GREATEST(VALUES(count), count) ;
```

**Warning:** This will fail if the passed value for `count` is `NULL` (instead of `2`). It will update the column with `NULL`. So, it's better to use the `IF()` or a `CASE` clause.

Unless you prefer the (there goes the elegance ...):

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
  count = GREATEST(COALESCE(VALUES(count), count), count) ;
```

Comment: my col is NOT NULL so i don't have this problem

Comment: Yes, because `GREATEST(5, NULL)` will result in `NULL`. So if by any chance you send `INSERT INTO tbl (count, otherID) VALUES (NULL, 'a') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE count = GREATEST(VALUES(count), count) ;` will replace the existing value in the row with `NULL`.
`

Comment: Ah yes, if the column is `NOT NULL`, the update to Null will fail with error, so **no problem**.

Comment: Can you please take a look at my [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32154794/how-to-control-the-errors-in-on-duplicate-key-using-if-function), It is related with this answer.

Answer (score 5):

Haven't tested it, but I think this should work.

```
INSERT INTO tbl (count, otherID) VALUES(2,'a')
ON DUPLICATE KEY 
UPDATE count = IF(VALUES(count) > count, VALUES(count), count)
```